# How to get the aggregation of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, algorithm

I am trying to aggregate my list of orders im getting in my database into an array of orders with different prices.

Example of array from my db:

```
[{
id: 1,
price: 10,
item: 'apple'
}, {
id: 2,
price: 10,
item: 'apple',
}, {
id: 3,
price: 20,
item: 'apple'
}]
```

i want to aggregate the orders based on the price ... if the price is the same make them into one array

what i want to return:

```
[{
price: 10,
item: 'apple',
quantity: 2
}, {
price: 20,
item: apple,
quantity: 1
}]
```

so as seen above if the price is the same aggregate them to one object and increase the quantity and return that to my users.

Comment: You can do this with a for loop or with `reduce()`.

Comment: which can be faster, the array might be in the thousands

Comment: You should consider modifying your database table to store quantity directly. You will probably also need to make the `item` field unique.

Comment: First, write a solution that works. Then you can decide if it is fast enough.

Comment: please add what does not work.

Comment: Your database may already have this functionality (aggregation).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  price: 10,
  item: 'apple'
}, {
  id: 2,
  price: 10,
  item: 'apple',
}, {
  id: 3,
  price: 20,
  item: 'apple'
}];

let x = data.reduce((items, item) => {
  let found = false;
 delete(item.id)
  items.forEach(el => {
    if (el.price == item.price && el.item == item.item) {
      found = true;
      el.quantity++;
    }
  })
  if (!found) {
    item.quantity = 1;
    items.push(item)
  }


  return items
}, [])


console.log(x)
```